# How To Receive Bytes From Server?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx

the sever is sending me an array of arrays of bytes `[[Byte]]` or `List<List<Byte>>`. A small sample looks like this `[[102, 222, 111], [92, 22, 111], [142, 122, 32]]` when writing this into a file, we get an executable, don't mean to compare with iOS but there I simnply do something like `let data = Data(bytes)` and then `data.write(to: "path/file.jpg")`. I can't get far as right when my application receives the JSON with the bytes and tried to deserialize it into:

```
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class ServerResponse(
    val fileRaw: List<List<Byte>>?
)
```

The application with the following error --> `Unexpected JSON token at offset 1829: Failed to parse 'byte'`

I know I will still have some troubleshooting after solving this, like actually writing this into an executable, but that is outside of the scope of this question.

How can I receive and serially an array of arrays of bytes (VISUALLY `[[Byte]]` or `List<List<Byte>>`)?

Comment: Make you response type generic Response type only not byte  only like Response of retrfoit.  When you do response.body()  it  will give  you the byte array

Comment: I think you need to describe things a bit more clearly.  You talk about JSON, but nothing here parses JSON.  Serializable is not the same as JSON serialization.  And I see nothing here that's making a server request, so you gave us only a small portion of the relevant code.

Comment: @GabeSechan hey! So, Serializable from Kotlinx parses JSON, maybe you got it confused with another library? The server requests is simple, really just a @GET(https://server.com/my_scenario) so I did not think it would be relevant to add that.